# MS Access query - only show the record with the most recent date

Tags: ms-access

I have ONE table in my DB called tblTraining - it imports a CSV file of training records.  I want to be able to build a query that will filter out duplicate records but pick the one with the most recent completion date.

Example:

| FirstName | LastName | Course | Class | CompleteDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Smith | 123 | Training A | 12/1/2020 |
| Marie | Parsons | 439A | Training C | 4/5/2012 |
| Marie | Parsons | 439A | Training C | 12/5/2015 |
| Bob | Smith | 123 | Training A | 1/3/2021 |
| Bob | Smith | 123 | Training A | 7/6/2021 |
| Marie | Parsons | 439A | Training C | 8/3/2021 |

I need a query that would return the following:

| FirstName | LastName | Course | Class | CompleteDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Smith | 123 | Training A | 7/6/2021 |
| Marie | Parsons | 439A | Training C | 8/3/2021 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try an aggregate (GROUP BY) query that includes all those fields except CompleteDate in GROUP BY clause with Max(CompleteDate) expression. Use Access query designer. Really a very basic query.

Comment: to do a Group By query in the query designer select TOTALS in the ribbon.  This will give you access to the total row.

Answer (score 1):

Someone linked this question in another question and I see that there is no response here so I will put my answer here as well.

The functionality that you are really looking for is done via a windows functionality which databases other than Access have. So you will need to do something different.

Here's how you do that in SQL Server for example which still requires a subquery...

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT key, rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY course ORDER BY CompletionDate)
      FROM table) sub
ON t.key=sub.key and sub.rn=1
```

However, for Access I chose to provide this answer with a subquery, but if you think visually (like Access' GUI interface), you can consider making a view for the subquery and then joining that way.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tableTraining t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT course, Max(CompletionDate) maxCompDate
    FROM tableTraining
    GROUP BY course) sub 
ON t.course=sub.course and t.CompletionDate=sub.maxCompDate
```

Basically, the view/subquery is returning just the business key (I assumed course was business key but it could be class or both course and class in your sample data [you will still need to determine that]) of the row in aggregate. And you use that key to get the entire row that you want.

Comment: I am not sure why this needed editing to capitalize everything. No one I know uses that.