# MS Access Aggregate Query Questions - only show record with most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate

I want to do exactly what this person asked about: [MS Access query - only show the record with the most recent date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035546/ms-access-query-only-show-the-record-with-the-most-recent-date)

BUT - I'm new to aggregate queries and need more details.

1. Do I remove "Group By" from the Total row under the CompleteDate field?
2. Under which field do I put the expression "Max(CompleteDate)"?

Without answers to these questions, I can't really expand on the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to show more fields other than those in the GROUP BY or Max expression, that will require a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

In other databases you would use a window function like row_number in SQL Server. But in access you can do this with a subquery...

```
select t.*
from tableTraining t
inner join
(select course,Max(CompletionDate) maxCompDate
from tableTraining
group by course) sub on t.course=sub.course and t.CompletionDate=sub.maxCompDate
```

Note: You will get dups when there are ties.

Note2: I am assuming you want the entire row for the most recently completed course.

Note 3: Not sure that course was the item being grouped as the same result could be accomplished with Class or using both.